# Flutter - Reorderable list with ability to scroll to index

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm trying to build a Flutter list with the following requirements:

1. The list can be reordered by moving items with touch gestures
2. The list can be scrolled imperatively by providing an index or key
3. The list widget needs to be available for iOS, Android and the Web.

For the first requirement, I found [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html), which appears perfect for this use case.

But I couldn't find a way to scroll to an inside with this particular list. What I've found was that I should use a [ScrollablePositionedList](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list). But these two don't seem compatible with each other. Am I missing something?

How do these two widgets can work with each other? If they can't, how would you build such a list?

Thank you in advance.